# How to bind the values between two classes

Tags: python, kivy

```
class Controls(BoxLayout):   
    delta_value=NumericProperty()
    max_value=NumericProperty()
    solar_value=NumericProperty()
    hysteresis=NumericProperty()
    busy_image=StringProperty('125.png')
    temp_solar=NumericProperty()
    temp_pool=NumericProperty()


    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Controls, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.set_value, 1)

    def PID_an_aus(self, instance, value):
        if value is True:
           pass

        else:
            pass

    def set_value(self, *args):


    # I want to pass temp_solar and temp_pool from PoolApp from read_temperature function



        print "Temperature",self.temp_solar, self.temp_pool 
        print "Delta",self.delta_value
        print "Max", self.max_value
        print self.hysteresis



class PoolApp(App):

    temperature=ListProperty()
    temp_sensor = DS18B20()

    temp_solar=NumericProperty(0.0)
    temp_pool=NumericProperty(0.0)




    def build(self):
        self.temp_sensor.start()

        Clock.schedule_interval(self.read_temperature, 0)


    def read_temperature(self, temperature):

        if not self.temp_sensor.temp_queue.empty():
            self.temperature = self.temp_sensor.temp_queue.get()
            self.temp_solar=self.temperature[0]
            self.temp_pool=self.temperature[1]
      #how to pass these values to Controls class       


    def on_stop(self):
        self.temp_sensor.running = False
        sys.exit()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    PoolApp().run()
```

Comment: I know that most of you will ignore it and won't answer. I have tried different methods of binding and I get always final value equal zero. I must make the same stupid mistake and can't see it, please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am new here, and I planned to post this in comments, but i am below 50 reputations to do that. So, here is mine conclusion.
Your problem is that you are trying to pass values between classes, and to mine understanding that is not possible (if I am wrong, somebody will correct me).

You need to create **objects** from those classes and then exchange data between them. I have written dummy code based on your code (i do not have that sensor to use it, so I used two dummy values in list)

Also, i believe that there is no need for "App" inheritance in PoolApp like you did, because you only need regular class. So, i created new class (Tempar) to actually get the temperatures, and then created object from that class in new PoolApp. Take a look, and see will it help you.

Btw, mine code is in python 3.x, so you will have to change print command to python2.x in order to work...

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, NumericProperty, ListProperty
from kivy.graphics.context import Clock
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class Controls(BoxLayout):   
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.temp_solar=NumericProperty()
        self.temp_pool=NumericProperty()
        self.delta_value=NumericProperty()
        self.max_value=NumericProperty()
        self.hysteresis=NumericProperty()
        #super(Controls, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        #Clock.schedule_interval(self.set_value, 1)

    def PID_an_aus(self, instance, value):
        if value is True:
           pass
        else:
            pass

    def set_value(self, *args):
        print("Temperature",self.temp_solar, self.temp_pool )
        print("Delta",self.delta_value)
        print("Max", self.max_value)
        print(self.hysteresis)

class Tempar():
    def __init__(self):
        self.temperature=[111,222]
        self.temp_sensor = []
        self.temp_solar=NumericProperty(0.0)
        self.temp_pool=NumericProperty(0.0)
        #self.temp_sensor.start()
        #Clock.schedule_interval(self.read_temperature, 0)

    def read_temperature(self, temperature):
        self.temp_solar=self.temperature[0]
        self.temp_pool=self.temperature[1]
        self.tmp=[self.temp_solar,self.temp_pool]
        return self.tmp


class PoolApp(App):
    #create object for each class and exchange values
    t=Tempar()
    c=Controls()
    c.temp_solar=t.read_temperature(t.temperature)[0]
    c.temp_pool=t.read_temperature(t.temperature)[1]
    print(c.temp_solar)
    print(c.temp_pool)
    #and here are your printouts
    c.set_value()        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    PoolApp().run()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried the code and got an error:
 c.temp_solar=t.read_temperature(t,t.temperature)[0]
 TypeError: unbound method read_temperature() must be called with Tempar instance as first argument (got WidgetMetaclass instance instead)

Comment: hmm, it works for me. Although, i think that we should create __init__ in Tempar class and put temperature and other values inside of that __init__ and then we should call t=Tempar() (note the brackets)... I can not check it now, since I am in a hurry, but I will try to check it alter...

Comment: hey, I have changed the code a little. Can you try again to see does it works?

Comment: It was working before when I included the brackets. i have implemented the code into my program and as a output from Controls the print returns correct values and defaults one every second one. I try to figure out why?

Comment: That is because of this line: `Clock.schedule_interval(self.set_value, 1)`. In your __init__ you are calling set_value function that is printing all values - and Clock function is set to execute that function every second. If your initial problem is solved, can you press the tick on the left to mark the answer as good one?

Comment: But I need to run it every second and compare the temperatures values and values from roulette and make some calculations.What I should use instead?

Comment: But then it is working OK, i suppose. If you remove "print" then it will not be printed, but instead of print you can put your function for calculations and return your desired values. Then you can use that returned values as you want.

Comment: Sorry what kind of tick, where?

Comment: On the upper-left of answer you have a tick that needs to be clicked once when your question is answered.

Comment: May I ask you one more question because #they" block" me for asking stupid questions?

Comment: class Controls(BoxLayout):   
 ........
 source=StringProperty('125.png')
 def __init__(self, **kwargs):
  super(Controls, self).__init__(**kwargs)
  
 def set_temp(self,instance,value):
  self.temp_queue= value
  self.temp_solar=self.temp_queue[0]
  self.temp_pool=self.temp_queue[1]
  if self.temp_solar >= self.temp_pool:
   
   self.source= '"100.zip"'
  elif self.temp_solar <= self.temp_pool: 
   self.source='"125.png"'
 def callback(self,instance,value):
  self.source=value
  return self.source ......wait for 2nd part my <kv> file

Comment: Image:
                       
                        size: 40, 40
                        source: controls.callback(self, self.source)                              The problem is I can't update image and apply source with conditions i have in Controls class. Sorry for the mess but I don't know how to send you my files. I really appreciate your help